# My filters seem to be applied in wrong order

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to join frames into a video with some parameters.
Here is a sample of the commands I run :

> "ffmpeg -y -r 24 -f image2 -i "C:\Users\Pictures\me\frame%04d.bmp" -filter_complex "[0:v]select=between(n,0,76)[selected];[selected]crop=in_w:in_h-60-60:0:60[cropped];[cropped]scale=w=2*ceil(2048.0/2*0.5):h=2*ceil(858.0 /2*0.5) " -c:v libx264 -q:v 1 -b:v 2M "C:\Users\me\Video\output.mp4""

When I run this command I have calculated the size of my cropping on the frames to remove black rectangles at the top and bottom of the frame (I tried using cropdetect but it doesn't fit my usecase so I'm using another soft).So my first that was that ffmpeg would crop on the input stream so it would only crop my black rectangles. But when I change my scale it crops a part of the image.

So my understanding is that ffmpeg crops after scaling (maybe I'm wrong) and if I get the crop parameters on the input images it is sure the they will be wrong if I apply them on the scaled video.

I tried using ";" and "," to separate my filters. I tried naming and not naming my streams between filters. Nothing seems to solve my issue.

What could I do to fix that or am I understanding the issue incorrectely?
Thanks in advance

Comment: *ffmpeg crops after scaling* --> ffmpeg applies filters in the specified order; in this case crop then scale.

Answer (score 0):

So actually I didn't understand the problem correctly. The filters are indeed applied in the correct order but it seems like "scale" crops my video again so I'm losing the bottom of my images.
I'm gonna investigate that.